# angular async model of array

Tags: angular, forms, observable

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(model)" #modelForm="ngForm">
    <div *ngFor="let model of model$ | async">
        <input name="{{model.id}}data1" [(ngModel)]="model.data1" />
        <input name="{{model.id}}data2" [(ngModel)]="model.data2" />
    </div>
    <button type="button" (click)="addModel()">Add</button>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

What I wanna achieve is:

1. If the model is empty, the view should show 2 empty inputs for each of the model's property. And when I submit the form, the `onSubmit(model)` should give me the dummy model with the values I just put in in the form.
2. If the model is not empty, the form shows all the models and the submit event should give me all the models with the updated value.
3. When I click the `Add` button, a new empty model should be added to the view. When I submit the form, I should be able to get all the models with updated values.

Comment: You should probably look at [Angular reactive forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms). There is `FormArray`, that may do what you want.

Comment: Include your ts file

Comment: @muradm I personally don't like to manipulate GUI with code.

Comment: @SunilSingh My `ts` file does not have any fancy stuff. `model$` is the component class' property and all functions are stubs.

Comment: @Antediluvian, what do you mean by "manipulate GUI with code"?

Comment: @muradm HTML code is GUI and should only be in HTML file. Little javascript code should change the DOM or HTML.

Comment: @Antediluvian, why do you use Angular then? It is whole framework that generates DOM from TypeScript/JavaScript code? :)

Comment: @muradm That is the framework mechanism. Normal code don't get to deal with it. I have got large C# projects with code generating HTML. As the project grows, it is harder and harder to debug because all the HTML is generated at runtime.

Comment: @Antediluvian, Angular by it self translates all your HTML code in templates into javascript any way. And that framework has intentional use-cases. This specific use-case to handle dynamic forms, have necessary instrumentation within framework. Here is it in action  https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-angular-async-model-of-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now you are using the async Array however you need to maintain the local array in the component and you can modify it as per requirement.

Whenever you get the Models from the API you can update the local model array.

### ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';

  models = [];
  min = 2;

  getModels(){
    let need = this.min - this.models.length;
    if(need > 0){
      for(let i=0; i<need; i++){
         this.models.push(this.getEmptyModel());
      }
    }
    return this.models;
  }

  fetchData(){
    this.getModelsFromAPI().subscribe(response=>{
         this.models = response;
      });
  }

  addModel(){
    this.models.push(this.getEmptyModel());
  }

  onSubmit(){
    console.log(this.models);
  }



  getEmptyModel(){
    return {data1 : "", data2 : ""}
  }

  getModelsFromAPI(){
   return of( [
   {
    "data1": "AA",
    "data2": "BB"
   }
   ])
  }

}
```

### html

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #modelForm="ngForm">
    <div *ngFor="let model of getModels(), let i = index">

        <input name="data1{{i}}"  [(ngModel)]="model.data1" />
        <input name="data2{{i}}"  [(ngModel)]="model.data2" />
    </div>
    <button type="button" (click)="addModel()">Add</button>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    <button type="button" (click)="fetchData()">Fetch Data</button>
</form>
```

Here is the sample application as per requirement - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qnbtdb

Comment: I would improve that, using function call in `*ngFor` is not very good idea and probably bad practice. Will have negative impact and unexpected behaviors for Angular's change detection.

Comment: @muradm - yes, its d not a good idea to call function in repeated section however it will not have any impact on the Angular CD process. It not recommended because of the performance however as per current implementation there won't be any.

Comment: sure, for this specific case no problems will have, just spreading bad practice, IMO, especially for new comers and copy-pasters :)

Comment: @SunilSingh Thanks for your demo. But I won't click the button to fetch the new data. By the look of your code, it looks like I can't put an async array into the template? I always have to subscribe to the observable and construct a normal array myself?

Comment: @muradm I can't get the async array work so I would like to see how experts handle it. You are rude to judge people like that. The code I put up onto here is not even close to what I have been coding. Copy & paste just won't work for me!

Comment: @Antediluvian - Add button is working for me. Please let me know if you getting encountered with any error. Second, yes you need to subscribe for async data since there is some logic has to be performed once we get the data. You can handle it by creating duplicated template with two items but I won't recommend that. Anyway you will be subscribing it in one place I believe.

Comment: @Antediluvian, that was not a) rude, b) addressed to you. That comment was related to the example illustrated in the answer.